# Show there exist countable set containing an uncountable family $F$ of subsets such that $A,B \in F$ and $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove there exists a countable set $C$ containing an uncountable family $F$ of subsets such that if $A,B$ are in $F$ and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset $, then either $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$.

I tried to show this by giving an explicit example, consider the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and take it's power set $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{Z} )$, I know that $\mathbb{Z} $ is countable and $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{Z} )$ is uncountable
, can you help?

Comment: I think you want $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ in the statement of what you want to prove.  If one is contained in the other and not the empty set, the intersection is not zero.

Comment: You might have $A = \{\emptyset\}$ and $B = \{\emptyset , ... \}$ so that this statements makes sense.

Comment: @SubGenius:  no, then $A \cap B = \{\emptyset\}$, which is not the same as $\emptyset$

Comment: @SubGenius:  no, each of them has $\emptyset$ as an element, so their intersection is the same as $A$, which is not empty.  It is the difference between the empty set and the set containing the empty set.  $A$ is the latter.

Comment: @RossMillikan but $A \cap B = x \in A \land x \in B$, but $\emptyset$ is both in A and B. $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$

Comment: @SubGenius:  No, $A \cap B=\{x|x\in A \wedge x \in B\}$.  The intersection has $\emptyset$ as an element, because it is an element of both $A$ and $B$.  That means the intersection is not the empty set.  It is the set which contains the empty set as its only element.

Comment: I am really sorry about this, but I was just informed this was a typo. It's actually $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @RossMillikan ah right!, I forgot it was a set by itself, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Kthamil:  you should correct the question using the edit button at the bottom so people don't have to find it in the comments.